# How to know when user press Back in an app started by my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, back-button

Is there a way to know when user press the back button in application called (via intent) by my application?

I started an application (like Acrobat Reader) from my application. When the user press back button in Acrobat Reader application, how can i know that?

Comment: `onResume()` is called when your `Activity` regains focus.

Answer (score 0):

when you open app from your activity, your activity goes invisible, therefore onStop() is called and on return it goes to onRestart() and onStart() methods.. where you can implement what you want

further for life cycle of activity see

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: startActivityForResult is a solution too?
onActivityResult is called when the user press back?
In advance, i know the lifecycle, i just think that im so focused in this app that i forgot basic things. THANKS MAN!! hahahha

Comment: Generally you would use `onResume()` not `onStart()`. `startActivityForResult()` will not return a value if you call an external `Activity`.

Comment: And if the user close the application with acrobat reader open? Theres a way to know that?
I dont know...something like, override the methods from the activity (acrobat) that is being called?

Comment: if your application is destroyed with that your activities are also destroyed than you will not return to your app to detect either it is return from another app or not

Comment: you can create a flag with value false, and if the other app  is started from it than make it true, and on return to your activity check it onResume() either app was started from it or not... hope this logic will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> When the user press back button in Acrobat Reader application, how can i know that?

There is no guaranteed way to do what you are asking. Take the following scenario...

Suppose an `Activity` in my app starts a 3rd party app - in this case my `Activity` goes to the background and enters a 'stopped' state. If the user presses BACK then my `Activity` will be restarted and resumed...but that's it. There's no indication of why or how my `Activity` has been restarted and resumed.

In the case of a 3rd party app there is no guaranteed way of knowing if the user pressed the BACK button. Even if you started the `Activity` with `startActivityForResult()` not all 3rd party apps will return any result.

Now take a different scenario...

An `Activity` in my app starts a 3rd party app and then the user hits the HOME button. At this point the device goes to the HOME screen (my app and the 3rd party app are now stopped and invisible as the user is at the HOME screen). The user then goes to Recent Apps and selects my app and presses the BACK button which terminates my app `Activity`. They then go to Recent Apps and select the 3rd party app my app started and press BACK which terminates that app. My app's `Activity` has already been terminated therefore there's no way it can be notified of how the 3rd party app was terminated.

Comment: So if my app calls the acrobat to open a book, there's no way I can know if the user has "closed the book". That's it?



I'm asking this because every time the user closes a book I have to send a request to server

Comment: @WitaloBenicio : You can't control Acrobat Reader or any other 3rd party app or expect to get a guaranteed result from any 3rd party app if it is started by your app. If you need to do something in a more controlled manner then you need to write your own "book" reader at which point you can use `startActivityForResult` and keep everything within your own app.

Comment: Do you know any way to build a PDF viewer?

Comment: No I don't, sorry. Try searching on Google - I think there are some open source libraries but I'm not sure.